# 2GB of shared memory used as shown in free

Tags: ubuntu, shared-memory

*OS: Ubuntu 16.04*

`free` output indicated about 2GB of shared memory.
The shared memory was still allocated after a *logout*, and no particular process from `top` list was occupying it.

`ipcs -m` did not indicate any singular process (or sum) with this consumption.

`sync` or `sysctl vm.drop_caches={1..3}` did not reduce the shared memory. (only the cache as expected)

After the fact I know that the issue was caused by a faulty attempt to write to block device with `dd`, which caused a physical file to be created in `/dev/` (see answer).

for reference:

```
> grep ' /dev ' /proc/mounts 
udev /dev devtmpfs rw,nosuid,relatime,size=1941504k,nr_inodes=485376,mode=755 0 0
```

What steps are needed in general to find out what is occupying shared memory?

Comment: Hi! Even when you intend to answer your own question, I think it would be best to phrase your question as a question (e.g. "How to free 2GB of shared memory I cannot seem to get rid of?"). This helps make it clearer exactly what questions you will be answering.

Comment: Question must be phrased to be answerable here. Provide details. Otherwise we'll close it as non-reproducible or another off-topic.

Comment: tried to rewrite the text as a question.

Comment: The updated question is clearer now, and I *would* vote to reopen it, but based on your answer it's clear that this was caused by a typo and has no other "correct" answer, so I will be voting to leave it closed.

Comment: I have no idea if I have violated the rules, if so sorry to have done so.
It was an unexpected cause and effect situation - I would not expect a physical file in `/dev/` to have an effect on memory calculation. Since I'm not sure it's a bug, I'm solely reporting about it in case someone else encounters it.

Comment: What type of filesystem is your `/dev` on? `grep ' /dev ' /proc/mounts ` ought to tell you (3rd column). I'm guessing it's one of the in-memory filesystems.

Comment: If you write to a file in `/dev` and then you read it back, you get the original content. That content has to be stored somewhere. On modern Linux systems, it's in RAM. This *could* be useful information for others. (It isn't a bug, but it's behavior that might be surprising if you haven't thought about how it works.) However, your question, as it stands, is not useful to anybody else: there's nothing in the question indicating that you did anything unusual in `/dev`.

Comment: @IljaBek - I don't think you broke any rules; it's just not clear to me how anyone else could get from your Question to The Answer. It's certainly useful information, so thank you for sharing it! Self-answered questions are [allowed and encouraged](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Indeed, if you add to the question that you were using `dd` to write an image to a block device — something to show you were using an `of=/dev/…` as root — that'd probably connect the two.

Answer (score 1):

The reason was me making a typo in dd command, writing to a physical file /dev/mmcblk1:

```
 > ll /dev/mmcblk*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1.9G 2017-11-03 18:09 /dev/mmcblk1 
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 179, 0 2017-11-03 18:10 /dev/mmcblk2
```

after removing the SD card and noticing the mistake, I have removed the physical file and the cache usage dropped by these 2GB.

example to reproduce:

```
> free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3.7G        1.7G        919M        163M        1.2G        1.6G

> sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/BIG  bs=1M count=700 status=progress
700+0 records in
700+0 records out
734003200 bytes (734 MB, 700 MiB) copied, 0.743527 s, 987 MB/s

> free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3.7G        1.7G        221M        859M        1.8G        982M

> sudo rm /dev/BIG

> free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3.7G        1.7G        904M        160M        1.2G        1.6G
```

Comment: Don't forget to run `sync` after `dd` finishes.